# MVVM Call Command from CommandBinding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, icommand

I wanted to bind a `CommandBinding` to a ViewModel `ICommand`, this way, when the user hits `Delete` I can trigger my ViewModel's delete logic.

The only way I know how to do it is in code behind, with this:

```
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" Executed="OnDeleteCommand" />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Any MVVM ways of achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for the delete logic :

```
<Window x:Class="DeleteCommandStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Button Content="Delete" 
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.deleteCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

One note here:

- The delete Button has to reach the DataContext of the ViewModel, so that syntax let us go the DataContext of the Window which in fact is exactly what we want.

  - For the CommandParameter we need the SelectedItem of the DataGrid so, using RelativeSource we are able to accomplish this.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> items { get; set; }

    public ICommand deleteCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        items.Add(new Model() { Name = "Name1" });
        items.Add(new Model() { Name = "Name2" });
        items.Add(new Model() { Name = "Name3" });
        items.Add(new Model() { Name = "Name4" });

        deleteCommand = new DeleteCommand(this);
    }

    public void DeleteHandler(object parameter)
    {
        items.Remove(parameter as Model);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Delete command:

```
public class DeleteCommand : ICommand
{
    private ViewModel _vm;
    public DeleteCommand(ViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.DeleteHandler(parameter);
    }
}
```

And the codebehind to set the DataContext:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

By sending the ViewModel reference to DeleteCommand we are able to call and send parameters to their methods.

We can choose to delete the item directly from the command:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
   _vm.items.Remove(parameter as Model);
}
```

I think that's about it, you have a working example now.

Comment: Reading quickly your code, I am not so sure this will work for me....you change the `DataTemplate` of the `Cells` and I already have them set, because I have some special kind of data that need proper visual representatition (like `bool` to `check_image`)

Comment: For my particular case I don't need a Command parameter because the `SelectedItem` is already bound to the ViewModel....but it's good that you added it, makes it more complete.

Comment: But my question is about CommandBindings, so When I hit the `Del` key, a Command is called...just the same can hapen in `Copy`, `Paste` etc...

Comment: Matt Hamilton has a nice article on this: http://matthamilton.net/commandbindings-with-mvvm but usually i use the above approach..check it out, it's well explained.